# DevExtreme datasource can't load Data Service data

Tags: html, wcf, devexpress, devextreme

I tried to accomplish the tutorial [here](http://help.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Documentation/Tutorial/Create_a_Mobile_App_in_Visual_Studio#Create_a_Mobile_App_in_Visual_Studio_Bind_to_Real_Data_Bind_Data_to_the_Categories_List), and when I used their data service, it worked just fine.
I modified the source to my data service (WCF Data Service v5.6, OData V2), and the list just shows the *Loading* sign and nothing happens. 
The code should load any data type, it just has to be mapped accordingly. My service is availabe through the browser, I checked.

Here is the code:

```
DevExTestApp.home = function (params) {
  var viewModel = {
    dataSource: DevExpress.data.createDataSource({
      load: function (loadOptions) {
        if (loadOptions.refresh) {
          try {
            var deferred = new $.Deferred();
            $.get("http://192.168.1.101/dataservice/dataservice.svc/People")          
            .done(function (result) {
              var mapped = $.map(result, function (data) {
                return {                  
                  name: data.Name
                }
              });
              deferred.resolve(mapped);
            });
          }
          catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
          }
          return deferred;
        }
      }
    })
  };
  return viewModel;
}
```

What else should I set?

Answer (score 0):

The `try-catch` block would not help is this case, because data loading is async. Instead, subscribe to the `fail` callback:

```js
$.get(url)
    .done(doneFunc)
    .fail(failFunc);
```

Another common problem with accessing a web service from JavaScript is [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Your OData service have to support either [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19808069/65899).